# starting with heroku; fail updating rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

after a few months learning a bit about rails and making some stuff local, I wanted to try to upload a simple rails app to heroku. Which, by the way, was a pain in the ass because of installing issues of Postgresql. But ok, that's done.

Now I create an app on heroku, I did the login, key thing, git, and uploaded. Was fine, very easy after all. I just uploaded an empty rails app, to try heroku.
Well, then I add a controller. Upload again via `git push heroku master` and not so fine! I did scaffold, for my *articulo* controller. And I wasn't able to open the URL once pushed to heroke on someurl/articulos. I got an 404 heroku message here: http://enigmatic-scrubland-8865.herokuapp.com/articulos

Then I create a controller for the home site and get rid of the "welcome aboard" default site. Again push heroku... On terminal I got messages all updated, and lauching. All fine.

But then I access and again, the "welcome aboard" default page.

Locally it works fine. But now I'm not sure if I'm doing it well. It scares me that no failing messages are to see nowhere, but obviously it fails.

After editing my rails app, I always do this:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "init"
$ git push heroku master
```

Like the documentation says on heroku. But, no error and no updating.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see from [heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), the `git init` part is only to be done on the first initial creation of the git repo, not "After editing my rails app".

In other words, you shouldn't have to "always do" a `git init` after editing your rail apps.

For the first push, I would recommend a:

```
git push -u heroku master
```

That way, all the subsequent push will be a simple:

```
git push
```

Comment: beside that, check what `git branch` returns to check you are not in a DETACHED HEAD mode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714)

Comment: Thank you VonC. Also I didn't knew that I should have run `heroku rake db:migrate`, create rake seems to happen "magically" on push.